# localhost refused to connect after upgrading to High Sierra

Tags: network, high-sierra

After upgrading Mac to High Sierra and some other upgrades there is a problem connecting to localhost.
Actually, upgrading to High Sierra was OK but according to the Mac update history the last update was to MacOS High Sierra 10.13.3 Supplemental Update.  It was kind of strange because the problem started after I hit restart with update but this update required one more specific restart.

The Spring Boot applications work fine. I can connect to them from a test client using opened ports. A connection to the Apache server form the browser also works fine. However, the browser connections to my applications are not working

Comment: Can you confirm that the application/service is running and is fully compatible with High Sierra? What version of macOS did you upgrade from? Is there a recent update to the application/service you are using?

Comment: @drivec, Please, see my edited text, no application updates happened

Comment: The question (particularly considering several versions in the edit history) is somehow chaotic and inconsistent. Major details (apacheconfig test, ps|grep, nmap and log/error messages) are missing.

Comment: @klanomath, i added some clarifications based on your questions. I also found the solution, please see my response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Chrome security certificate required for these applications stopped working after upgrades.  Reinstalling the certificate solved the problem

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Chrome security required for these applications stopped working"? I am experiencing a similar issue, but your self-submitted answer is vague.

Comment: Sorry, do not remember the exact steps, remember that I needed to reinstall the particular Chrome security certificate.  This certificate was specific for the application  I was connecting to

Comment: I ended up resolving it through the httpd.conf, but thanks anyway.