# safari can't connect to localhost even configtest return no syntax error on Apache file

Tags: safari, high-sierra, apache, webserver

I have an iMac with High Sierra 10.13. It is an old machine so it cannot get further OS upgrade. I tried to reach localhost but it failed to connect with either Chrome or Safari. I tried looking into the httpd file, check the directory stated in the file,  uncomment the line for php7. I checked the index file as well. Ran the configtest on httpd file and showed no syntax error. restarted Apache and still can't connect. Also tried swapping the pre-update httpd file, also no joy. Anyone can help?

Comment: What exactly was the error?

Comment: When I type localhost on the browser search box, instead of getting "it works", I am getting failure to connect message. I have followed the advice on https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/351031/i-can-t-connect-to-localhost-on-mac-high-sierra and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320161/localhost-refused-to-connect-after-upgrading-to-high-sierra but nothing works.

Comment: What is the xact error message. This should be in the question